# remove this.class function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function connected to a class, that lets me remove it by className.
the problem I have is when I have two elements with the same class name. the function close both of the classes and not only the one that's selected.

I think that i use use a element.this function, but when I try it, none of the classes removes.

Any ideas ?

```
 function CloseEvent(){
        var CloseEvent = "close";
        var addClassArr= document.getElementsByClassName(CloseEvent);
        for(var i=0; i<addClassArr.length; i++){
            var addClass = addClassArr[i];
            addClass.addEventListener("click", closebutton, true);
        }       
        function closebutton() {

        var classToRemove = "dice-window-wrapper";
            var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);
            for (var i = 0;  i < elems.length; i--) {
                elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i])

            }
        } 


    }
    CloseEvent();
```

Comment: Could you post some html code of 2 elements this applies to? You can use this in the onclick or pass the event and get the event.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the html code to reflect the html used on your site.

```
<div class="dice-window-wrapper">
    <div class="dice-menubar-wrapper">
        <div class="close">
            close one
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dice-window-wrapper">
    <div class="dice-menubar-wrapper">
        <div class="close">
            close one
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then here is how to remove the clicked element:

```
function CloseEvent(){
        var CloseEvent = "close";
        var addClassArr= document.getElementsByClassName(CloseEvent);
        for(var i=0; i<addClassArr.length; i++){
            var addClass = addClassArr[i];
            addClass.addEventListener("click", closebutton, true);
        }       
        function closebutton(e) {
            var classToRemove = " "+"dice-window-wrapper"+" ";
            var obj=e.target;
            while((" "+obj.className+" ").indexOf(classToRemove)==-1){ 
                obj=obj.parentNode;
            }
            if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase()!="div"){
                console.log("something wrong in closebutton");
                return;
            }
            obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
        } 
    }
```

Note that this doesn't work at all in IE8 because getElementsByClassName is not supported not is the event passed in this way and there might be a problem with addEventListner. That's why I usually use jQuery.

Comment: Im using javascript for study purpose, I tried you code, it close one div element at the time, but its removing the "close" element :)

Anyhow, its always something :)

Comment: I've updated it with some extra checks so you can set multiple classes on the element to be removed. And do a safety check to make sure we are not trying to remove document from window. It now assumes that the element to be removed is always a div. Nice page for someone who is learning. You do know that most of that code is not IE8 compatible. If you'd like to run things in all browsers while maintaining uniform code (without if statements checking the browser all the time). you can use jQuery or another JS library.

Comment: Thank you, I actually began with JS for a couple of days ago, that's why all the questions here in stackOverflow :)
Well anyhow. I'm trying to use this code to remove a class named dice. but I get the error property 'className' of null .
the class is removed with my old function, but meets the same problem I asked for. it remove all the classes instead of the one I in.

Comment: That is because the clicked element does not have any parent with the class "dice", maybe it's case sensitive and the class is named Dice or its something else. Could you open it in firefox with firebug, then right click the elelent and choose inspect element. Go up the html to get the parent you're looking for and right click that? Then copy the html. If you could clean up some of the stuff you don't need and the code someone here can have a look at it.

Comment: Well actually its not called only "dice". since its an random array with six class names, so the path to the class is. <li class="dice dice-side-five"></li> but the only thing thats different is that "five" can change between one and six.

Im going to clean the code and uploadit again.

Comment: Maybe we can discuss it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23963/room-for-hmr-and-dymond

Answer (score 3):

> the function close both of the classes and not only the one that's selected.

That's wrong, since more than one are selected via `document.getElementsByClassName` - and all of them are removed correctly.

Instead of selecting elements by their class name, select the one [on which the event was fired](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) at.

```
function closebutton(e) {
    var elem = e.target; // or just the "this" keyword
    // elem is the <div class="close" />
    var wrapper = elem.parentNode.parentNode;
    // wrapper is the <div class="dice-window-wrapper" />
    wrapper.parentNode.removeChild(wrapper);
}
```

Comment: well everything is generated by javascript. so there barley any html code .

This is an tinyURL of where the project is.

http://felipeotarola.se/project1/

Comment: @Dymond thank you for posting the code. Checked in firebug (inspect element) and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to identify the object calling a JS function by using `this` to identify the triggering element like

```
function closebutton() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

e.g. Delete the SO logo!

```
function notSO(){this.parentNode.removeChild(this);}
document.getElementById("hlogo").addEventListener("mouseover", notSO, true);
```

Comment: Urgh, what was I thinking? You don't put `this` as an argument, just use it as edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your modified code:

```
 function CloseEvent(){
    var CloseEvent = "close";
    var addClassArr= document.getElementsByClassName(CloseEvent);
    for(var i=0; i<addClassArr.length; i++){
        var addClass = addClassArr[i];
        addClass.addEventListener("click", function(){ closebutton(this) }, true);
    }       
    function closebutton( elem ) {

    var classToRemove = "dice-window-wrapper";
        //var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(classToRemove);
        //for (var i = 0;  i < elems.length; i--) {
        //    elems[i].parentNode.removeChild(elems[i])
        //}
        // you have passed the element to be removed, directly remove it
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    } 
}
CloseEvent();
```

Comment: Why use an extra anonymous function for that?